# Moved wordpress site to new physical server (same hostname and IP) none of the navigation links work now

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, permalinks

After migrating a wordpress installation to a new physical server, none of the navigation links work.

**No changes were made to domain or IP.  DNS not affected.**

If I change `Permalinks` to Plain style:

```
https://example.org/?p=123
```

All navigation works exactly as expected.

If `Permalinks` are changed to any option other than Plain, clicking any of our navigation headings results in 404s.

**EDIT**, this appears in error log:

> [Mon May 02 08:28:26.441200 2022] [autoindex:error] [pid 65112:tid
> 140589194516224] [client x.x.x.x:50240] AH01276: Cannot serve
> directory
> /data/www/virtualhosts/example.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/asp_upload/:
> No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and
> server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

What am I missing here?

Comment: I am guessing, but it sounds to me like a caching issue. You must have had to change the dns settings to change physical servers. It sounds like the dns settings changes haven't fully taken effect and therefore new pages never accessed before are serving correctly from the new dns settings but old cached pages are still trying to be served via the old dns settings. Have you tried clearing your browser cache or accessing the site from a computer or browser that you haven't previously used to see what happens?

Comment: @jtowell - DNS was not updated since the IP and domain name remained the same.  The same behavior exists from different systems/browsers.  Since the Permalinks work fine under "Plain" why are they failing (without httpd error log data) when set to anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I was missing

```
AllowOverride All
```

from the Directory directive:

```
    <Directory /data/www/example.com/public_html>
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

Once that was added and httpd restarted, the fancy Permalinks work perfectly again.